# How to automatically sort in 1 column 2 different ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, sorting

I don't find a short way to describe it, so the best way is to show what I have and what I want excel to do:

I have this:

[image]

and this is what I want as result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two level Sort. Sort ascending on the Income then on the output:

[image]

Press OK:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I failed to mention I want to use formulas. I don't mind to have the values in order, just have the inpunt first, and then the outputs, and also be able to add more and still have them sorted